# cannot match strings in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having difficulty matching strings for locating duplicate records in my database.

If you look, you'll see that im `selecting the comment row where the comment column equals this comment`

**I used each comment respective to it's record but I thought I would get 2 records with commentids 2254915 and 50712 and instead they seem to only query for their respective comment.**

Theres something different about these 2 queries that I am not finding because the comment is the same.

```
    mysql> select * from comments where comment="35 dancers on the roster,  but if you head in there at 4 or 5 in the afternoon,  you might find 3 chicks.  The only thing I'd change in this place would be the seating-the same filthy chairs for the last ten years";
    +-----------+----------+---------+------------+----------+-------+--------+-----------+--------+------------+---------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+----------+--------+--------+
    | commentid | parentid | refno   | createdate | remoteip | locid | clubid | profileid | userid | legacyuser | mediaid | status | comment                                                                                                                                                                                                               | likes | dislikes | import | author |
    +-----------+----------+---------+------------+----------+-------+--------+-----------+--------+------------+---------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+----------+--------+--------+
    |   2254915 |        0 | 2519833 | 1328361720 |          |  3166 |  18950 |         0 |      0 |    1846155 |       0 |      1 | 35 dancers on the roster,  but if you head in there at 4 or 5 in the afternoon,  you might find 3 chicks.  The only thing I'd change in this place would be the seating-the same filthy chairs for the last ten years |     0 |        0 |      1 | Jess   |
    +-----------+----------+---------+------------+----------+-------+--------+-----------+--------+------------+---------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+----------+--------+--------+
    1 row in set (2.96 sec)

    mysql> select * from comments where comment="35 dancers on the roster, but if you head in there at 4 or 5 in the afternoon, you might find 3 chicks. The only thing I'd change in this place would be the seating-the same filthy chairs for the last ten years";
    +-----------+----------+---------+------------+----------+-------+--------+-----------+--------+------------+---------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+----------+--------+--------+
    | commentid | parentid | refno   | createdate | remoteip | locid | clubid | profileid | userid | legacyuser | mediaid | status | comment                                                                                                                                                                                                            | likes | dislikes | import | author |
    +-----------+----------+---------+------------+----------+-------+--------+-----------+--------+------------+---------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+----------+--------+--------+
    |     50712 |        0 | 2519833 | 1328343720 |          |  3166 |  18950 |         0 |  28128 |          0 |       0 |      1 | 35 dancers on the roster, but if you head in there at 4 or 5 in the afternoon, you might find 3 chicks. The only thing I'd change in this place would be the seating-the same filthy chairs for the last ten years |     0 |        0 |      0 | Jess   |
    +-----------+----------+---------+------------+----------+-------+--------+-----------+--------+------------+---------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+----------+--------+--------+
    1 row in set (2.39 sec)
```

Not quite sure whats going on here. Here's my code:

```
    require_once("../www/api");
    $locid=3166;
    $sql="select commentid,legacyuser,userid,comment,status from comments where /**datediff(now(),from_unixtime(createdate))>=60 and*/ locid=$locid and status>=1 order by createdate desc limit 20";
    $rs=mysqli_query($dbh,$sql);
    $cnt=0;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)){
      if($cnt<10){
        $cnt++;
        continue;
      }
      $cnt++;
      // variables declaration
      $commentid=(int)$row['commentid'];
      echo $commentid.'-';
      $legacyuser=(int)$row['legacyuser'];
      $userid=(int)$row['userid'];
      $comment=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh,$row['comment']);


      $status=$row[status];
      //echo $comment;

      // get active duplicates count
      //echo "select count(commentid) as count from comments where comment='$comment' and locid=608 and status!=-14"."\r\n";
      $cnt=mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($dbh,"select count(commentid) as count from comments where comment='$comment' AND locid=$locid AND status!=-14"));
      $cntActive=(int)$cnt[count];
      //die($cntActive);
      if($cntActive==1)continue;

      if($cntActive>1){
        //$comment=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh,$comment);
        $activers=mysqli_query($dbh,"select commentid from comments where comment='$comment' AND locid=$locid AND status!=-14");
        $icnt=0;
        while($irow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($activers)){
          //print_r($irow);
          if($icnt==0){
            $icnt++;
            continue;
          }
          $commentid=$irow['commentid'];
          echo "update comments set status=-14 where commentid=$commentid";
          mysqli_query($dbh,"update comments set status=-14 where commentid=$commentid");
          $icnt++;
        }
      }
    }
```

From what I see its bypassing the count as greater than 1 and we can see there are 2 distinct records but the comment is the same so i dont know why.

Comment: The 2 comments are not the same. `...afternoon,[SPACE][SPACE]you...` in the first, and `...afternoon,[SPACE]you..` in the second.

Comment: `in the afternoon,  you might` versus `in the afternoon, you might`.  The first has 2 spaces, the second 1 space after the comma. `MD5(comment)` can be your friend here.

Comment: @bishop is there a way to still match them as close to the same?

Comment: @jkushner Remove all whitespace from your string then compare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two comments are not the same. The first has one more space character in it than the second. The following would alert you to that fact, and should be your first "go to" when two things look alike but you're not sure if they are or aren't.

```
SELECT MD5(comment) FROM comments WHERE commentid IN (50712,2254915);
```

Since white space is the only distinction here, you might want to remove that white space, along the lines of:

```
SELECT REPLACE(comment, ' ', '') FROM comments;
```

This is in no way approximates a "close enough" match. You need to define better rules for that and implement a custom algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Carefully take a look at the sql statement, there is an extra space in the records.

```
"afternoon,  you might"
"afternoon, you might"
```